# How do I match two strings in two different string arrays with user input?

Tags: arrays, string, input, random

```
{
    String[] numbers = new String[5] ;  
    strArray[0] = ("Hellowrite1") ;
    strArray[1] = ("write2") ;
    strArray[2] = ("write3") ;
    strArray[3] = ("write4") ;
    strArray[4] = ("write5") ; 

{
    String[] answers = new String [5] ;
    answer[0] = ("1") ;
    answer[1] = ("2") ;
    answer[2] = ("3") ;
    answer[3] = ("4") ;
    answer[4] = ("5") ; 

}
```

If I have a random function displaying the 3rd string array (write4) and I need the user to input the number 4 for it to be correct, how would I do this?
Basically, the user's input should be doing the first string's string array and equal the second string's respective string array.

string array 0 matches the second string's string array 0 etc.

Comment: Not clear about what you want to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is what you are trying to do:

```
String userInput = "4";
int answerIndex = Arrays.asList(answers).indexOf(userInput);
String answer = numbers[answerIndex];
```

It might be more ideal to use a HashMap if you are simply mapping one to the other:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

But, the above should work.